# How to set a block variable in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting an `run-time error: 91 "Object variable or with block variable not set`

Here is my code, I don't what did i wrong

```
With Sheet1
lastrowcell = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
pr_high = 14
For n = pr_high To lastrowcell

Max = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(Cells(n - pr_high_1, 6), Cells(n, 6)))

If Max > 0 Then
    rowNum = .Columns(6).Find(What:=Max, after:=.Cells(n - period_high, 6), LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Row
    '>>>>At above line I'm getting an error.

    Range(Cells(n - pr_high_1, 8)).Formula = "=Count(" & Range(Cells(n - pr_high_1, 6), Cells(rowNum, 6)).Address(False, False) & ")"
End If

Next
```

Thanks in  advance.

Comment: what is pr_high_1?

Comment: which line is generating the error?

Comment: Can you show your Sheet1 variable declaration?

Comment: @ Karthick pr_high_1 is just `pr_high-1` i.e. 14-1=13

Comment: @SanjeevShinde, in this line **rowNum=.Columns(6).........** it will return error because you are substracting the same row numbers for ex: 14-14 -1 then it will be negative.

Comment: @SanjeevShinde what you exactly want please explain

Comment: So, for some times leave that variables. keep that `pr_high` as 14. I am getting an error at **rowNum=.Columns(6)..** that `Object variable or With block Variable not set`... I don't know why but... it was working some days back... Now I don't know what just happend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited** after OP's full code posting

I think I found two incorrect lines in your `Function calculate_high_low`, namely

1) in "Count Maximum High" block

```
rowNum = .Columns(6).Find(What:=Max, after:=.Cells(n - period_high, 6), LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlWhole, searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Row
```

should be

```
rowNum = .Columns(6).Find(What:=Max, After:=.Cells(n - period_high, 6), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Row
```

since you were looking at cell formula rather than at its content and thus you wouldn't catch the value you were looking for

2) in "Count Minium low" block

```
rowNum2 = .Columns(6).Find(What:=mymin, After:=.Cells(n - period_high, 6), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Row
```

should be

```
rowNum2 = .Columns(6).Find(What:=Min, After:=.Cells(n - period_low, 6), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Row
```

since you were looking at cell formula rather than at its content and thus you wouldn't catch the value you were looking for

moreover you were using `period_high` instead of `period_low`.

But other (I'd say more), than that, you'd always better:

- use Option Explicit statement at the very top of your module

  it'll force you to some extra work and define all variables and their type but will make both debugging and code maintenance much easier. for instance it'll have all variable names errors pop out, like most probably are both `pr_high`  vs `pr_high_1` and (maybe) `period_high` vs `period_high`
- use fully qualified reference for your ranges, up to worksheet and workbook ones
  to be sure you're point at the right worksheet of the right workbook, otherwise they'd default to active sheet and workbook

so here follows your `Function calculate_high_low` refactored for what above **only**:

```
Public Function calculate_high_low(com_tick_ask As String, rng As Variant)

Dim lastrowcell As Long, rowNum As Long, rowNum2 As Long
Dim pr_high As Long, period_high As Long, period_low As Long, pr_low As Long, pr_high_1 As Long, pr_low_1 As Long, n As Long
Dim Max As Double, Min As Double

Dim calcSht As Worksheet


    Range("A:A,E:E,F:F,H:H").Copy '<=it's referring to currently active sheet which, as it's currently called from sub "CommandButton1_Click" above, is the sheet with which the last opened ".csv" file shows
    Worksheets.Add

    Set calcSht = ActiveSheet 'it's the added new sheet

    With calcSht

        .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        'Range("C1").Value = "Formula High"
        'Range("D1").Value = "Count High"
        'Range("E1").Value = "Formula Low"
        'Range("F1").Value = "Count Low"

        .Range("1:1").Font.FontStyle = "Bold Italic"

        lastrowcell = .Range("B1", .Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Count
        'lastrowcell = .Range("B1:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlDown).Row).Count

        'count average of high and low
        .Range("F2:F" & lastrowcell).Formula = "=Average(" & .Range("B2:C2").Address(False, False) & ")"

        'long
        period_high = high_low.period_1.Text
        period_low = high_low.period_2.Text

        pr_high = period_high + 1
        pr_low = period_low + 1

        pr_high_1 = period_high - 1
        pr_low_1 = period_low - 1


        'Count Maximum High
        For n = pr_high To lastrowcell
            Max = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(.Cells(n - pr_high_1, 6), .Cells(n, 6)))

            If Max > 0 Then
               rowNum = .Columns(6).Find(What:=Max, After:=.Cells(n - period_high, 6), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Row
            'rowNum = WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(Cells(n - period_high, 6), Cells(n, 6)))
               Range(.Cells(n - pr_high_1, 8), .Cells(lastrowcell, 8)).Formula = "=Count(" & Range(.Cells(n - pr_high_1, 6), .Cells(rowNum, 6)).Address(False, False) & ")"
            End If
        Next



        'Count Minium low
        For n = pr_low To lastrowcell
            Min = WorksheetFunction.Min(Range(.Cells(n - pr_low_1, 6), .Cells(n, 6)))

            If Min > 0 Then
'                rowNum2 = .Columns(6).Find(What:=mymin, After:=.Cells(n - period_high, 6), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Row
                rowNum2 = .Columns(6).Find(What:=Min, After:=.Cells(n - period_low, 6), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Row
                'rowNum2 = WorksheetFunction.Min(Range(Cells(n - period_high, 6), Cells(n, 6)))
                Range(.Cells(n - pr_low_1, 10), .Cells(lastrowcell, 10)).Formula = "=Count(" & Range(.Cells(n - pr_low_1, 6), .Cells(rowNum2, 6)).Address(False, False) & ")"
            End If

        Next


        'Calculate Formula for High & Low

        'For high
        .Range("G2:G" & lastrowcell).Value = "=(" & period_high & "-" & .Range("H2").Address(False, False) & ")/" & period_high

        'For Low
        .Range("I2:I" & lastrowcell).Value = "=(" & period_low & "-" & .Range("J2").Address(False, False) & ")/" & period_low



    End With
    high_low.Hide

End Function
```

As i said, this should only be a starting point for you, since the whole code you posted lack good coding pattern and is very likely to fail the step right after this one, should what above fix this latter altogether.

but if you follow the proposed pattern you should more easily catch all possible issues, even those logic one since a clear code can have you concentrate on the algorithm he has to develope

Comment: It was not suppose to work, since you didn't even give all the code. rather it was supposed to possibly lead you to the "right" path as long as coding patterns are concerned. you may want to post the entire code and upload the data file ("Sheet1"?) and specify what the code is supposed to do and where (which line) do you get stuck and why (what error). and may people here would help you

Comment: @ user3598756 Here I am giving the link for my file https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwIYozURuftTSENVdHlGYjVOdkk

Comment: please upload an ".xlsx" file (not an ".xlsm" one, macro can be harmful...) and code (just update your Q pane code) separately.

Comment: Here is the code https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwIYozURuftTdDk5QjBEWkZJSTQ    Please, help...

Comment: see edited answer. I think you have a long way to go before having that whole code robust as you'd need. but I hope I gave you a good starting point

Comment: Yes, Its working... Thanks... N I am trying my best... Thanks for your suggestion also...

Comment: glad to be of help. If my answered fulfilled your question please mark it as accepted. thank you